# ModelState.IsValid is false during my post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EMail(SendMailData objModelMail, HttpPostedFileBase fileUploader,SendMailData smd)
    {
        //string Emailid = smd.To;
        //TryUpdateModel<SendMailData>(smd);
        //var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
        //var Context = new ValidationContext(ModelState, null, null);
        //var errors = ModelState.Where(v => v.Value.Errors.Any());
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        string from = "MYMAILID";
        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, objModelMail.To))
        {
            mail.Subject = objModelMail.Subject;
            mail.Body = objModelMail.Body;
            if (fileUploader != null)
            {
                string Filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUploader.FileName);
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUploader.InputStream, Filename));
            }

            //mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(eMailBox.Text));
            // mail.To.Add(objModelMail.To);
            //mail.From = new MailAddress(objModelMail.From);
            //mail.Subject = objModelMail.Subject;
            //string body = objModelMail.Body;
            //mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1", 25);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MYMAILID", "PASSWORD",from);
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Send(mail);
            ViewBag.message = "Send";
            mail.Dispose();
            return View("EMail", objModelMail);
        }
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This is my model:

```
public class SendMailData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You Can't Leave This Empty")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(([a-zA-Z0-9_'+*$%\^&!\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9:]{2,7})([,;]\W?(?!$))?)+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct email address")]
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

This is my View:

```
@model SampleUniversity1.Models.SendMailData
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EMail";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('@ViewBag.message' == 'Send') {
        alert("Email Sended Successfully");
    }
</script>
<h2>Mail</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        Send Mail
    </legend>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EMail", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    { 
        @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken();*@
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <input type="submit" value="Send" style="width: 100px;" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    To
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.To)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.To)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Subject
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Subject)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Attachment
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="fileUploader" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Body
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Body)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</fieldset>
```

When I enter all the values correct it will display no error only else part is processing
else part is execute ModelState.IsValid is false.

Comment: when posting a question, please specify what programming language you are using.

Comment: today only i post this question. i am very new to asp.net mvc4

Comment: What makes you think we need to see all that SmtpClient stuff? And all of the commented out code? What values are you entering? Have you checked that they are binding correctly to your model class?

Comment: bind when HttpGet method but not in post method it give me ModelState.IsValid is false only .. how to i correct it

Comment: This code is working good when i comment if(modlestate.isvalid)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `RequiredAttribute` on the `From` property, but I can't see any input for it in you view, so it will be null and `ModelState.IsValid()` will be false

Comment: see my model now i used RequiredAttribute in model

Comment: Yes I know! That the problem. It is required but you don't post any value for it, so validation fails because its null. Either remove the `Required` attribute from the property of add an input in your view so it has a value.

Comment: ya thank stephen muecke... my problem cleared and another problem is

Comment: The other problem is what? (best to ask a new question)

Comment: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: This is unrelated to the original question.  If you cant solve it, post a new question.